# PSIPRED Makefile "System cannot find the file specified"

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to download [PSIPRED](https://github.com/psipred/psipred) on my Windows 10 Computer. Cloned the Git repository into my computer, and downloaded GNU Make 3.81 for compiling the PSIPRED code. According to the installation instructions, I should run the following commands in Command Prompt to compile it, after which it will place the executables in the bin folder:

```
cd to-psipred-directory
cd src
make
make install
```

However, when I run this, I get the error:

```
cc -O sspred_avpred.c -lm -o psipred
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, cc -O sspred_avpred.c -lm -o psipred, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [psipred] Error 2
```

Here's the contents of the psipred MAKEFILE:

```
######################################################################
#   Makefile for PSIpred4                                        #
######################################################################

#### CC     Command to execute C compiler
#### CFLAGS Flags to pass to C compiler.

INCDIR      = .
CC      = cc

CFLAGS      = -O
LIBS        = -lm

all:        psipred psipass2 chkparse seq2mtx

install:
        /bin/cp psipred psipass2 chkparse seq2mtx ../bin

clean:
        /bin/rm -f psipred psipass2 chkparse seq2mtx

psipred:    sspred_avpred.c ssdefs.h sspred_net.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) sspred_avpred.c $(LIBS) -o psipred

psipass2:   sspred_hmulti.c ssdefs.h sspred_net2.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) sspred_hmulti.c $(LIBS) -o psipass2

chkparse:   chkparse.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) chkparse.c $(LIBS) -o chkparse

seq2mtx:    seq2mtx.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) seq2mtx.c $(LIBS) -o seq2mtx
```

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

PSIPRED is tooled for a UNIX-like operating system such as Linux or macOS, with tools that go by the conventional names for such systems.  Windows is a completely different beast.

The particular thing that your build attempt is presently tripping over appears to be the name of the C compiler.  Supposing that your system has one in the first place -- from Visual Studio, for example -- it does not go by the name `cc`, or it is not found in the exectable search path.  That's not the only issue with trying to use that makefile on Windows, however.

In principle, it should be possible to adapt it the program to Windows, but that takes more than just getting GNU Make, and it would probably take more than updating tool names in the Makefile(s), too (but who knows, you might get lucky!).

- You would have the greatest likelihood of success from installing the Windows Subsystem for Linus (WSL) and building and running the program within, but that's not as simple as it may sound.  Also, if successful, the result would run only inside your WSL container, which might not meet your needs.
- You could install Cygwin or MinGW, which take different approaches to providing Unix-like environments within native Windows.  Within one of these environment you (probably) could build the program, and these would make it possible to run it natively on the host Windows machine.  This is not as easy as it might sound, either, but it's a fairly common approach.
- You could, in principle, port the software to Windows, so that you can build it with native Windows build tools such as Visual Studio.  In practice, this is *decidedly* non-trivial for most Unix programs.
- Of course, you could also set up a full-blown Linux machine on which to build and run the program.  Although that requires more resources, it might be the overall easiest way to go.

Comment: I installed Cygwin, opened the terminal, and tried the same command. It still gives me the error:

`cc -O sspred_avpred.c -lm -o psipred
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, cc -O sspred_avpred.c -lm -o psipred, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
`make: *** [psipred] Error 2'`

Comment: @CrazyComputing, I'm sorry, I didn't mean to imply that simply installing Cygwin (or MinGW), would automagically make the problem go away.  "Within [it] you (probably) could build the program" is a different and rather more involved process than what you already tried, and beyond what I, at least, am prepared to support via SO.  Although Cygwin and MinGW are intended for pretty much just the kind of thing you want to do, they are complex tools mainly oriented toward people already familiar with Unix-like environments.

Comment: The main message you should receive is that Windows is often a difficult target for software designed for Unix (and the reverse is true, too.)  Getting PSIPRED running natively on Windows is a project with an uncertain prospect for success, and one that will require you to develop or recruit some expertise in one or more of several toolsets, depending on which specific direction(s) you choose to pursue.